# Cloud Apps and Single Sign-On (AD integration)

Tags: google-app-engine, active-directory, cloud, single-sign-on

I've been investigating some cloud vendors and the ability to implement single sign-on with them, especially when it comes to AD (Active Directory) integration.

So far I've learned that with Azure this is possible through ADFS and the AppFabric Access Control offer.

In AWS, since it is possible to create a VPN and see EC2 instances as a natural extension of a private datacenter, I believe implementing SSO would be rather simple (not sure if I'm right on this one... Please correct me if I'm wrong).

With App Engine though, even though there is some documentation on AD synchronization (not full integration) for Google Apps, I'm struggling to find out whether AD integration would be possible... Is there any strategy for that?

Any bit of information on cloud apps and AD integration will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

App engine apps can only call out to other services using HTTP or HTTPS, so you could not directly query an AD server.  Of course, I'm sure you could build a simple HTTP/LDAP bridge if one does not already exist.
UPDATE:  oops, I forgot about SDC,or [Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/docs/1.3/overview.html).  It is not exactly a HTTP/LDAP bridge, but can provide a bridge between your intranet and your Google App Engine app.

Answer (score 1):

You typicially don't need communication between the application (in this case running in GAE) and AD.

You would, instead, get a security token from and STS (ADFS) and then send the token to the app that is would be configured to accept and trust those tokens.

I'm not familiar w/ GAE  but assuming it accepts SAML tokens and understands WS-Federation, you can achieve SSO without ever exposing AD or synchronizing any information between AD and GAE (using ADFS for example)

This is a classic identity federation scenario.